# The rank of nodes in the longest directed path of a random DAG

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics

I am facing this problem for a long time, I wish I can find some help in here.

Let's consider a graph $G(V,E)$ such that an edge between a pair of node $u$ and $v$ exist with probability $p \in O(1)$. Let's assign identifiers for the vertices from 1 to $n$, where $n = |V|$. Now, direct each edge $(u,v)$ towards $v$ if $u > v$. We have what we call a *random graph order* $P$.

We define $L = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_m)$ as the longest directed path in $P$. That is, $x_i > x_{i+1}$ for all $1 \leq i < k$.  It is known that $|L| = \Theta(n)$. Define $\textit{rank}(x_i)$ as the position of $x_i$ in the set ${1, ..., n}$ (that is, the first, the second, ..., the $n$-th element in the total order constructed from the identifiers of $V$).

> **Question.** If we take any $x_i \in L$, what is expected rank of $x_i$?

My solution was to assume that $|L| = \frac{n}{t}$, and to assume that the path $L$ partitions the graph $G$ into $|L|$ layers. Thus, for the path $L = (x_1, \ldots, x_m)$ the expected rank of $x_i = (n - (t * i)) + \frac{1}{2} * t$. What do you think?

Comment: Hi @Ahmed, I modified your question with LaTeX. But there are some notations that is unclear to me (e.g. t and ti in the last paragraph.) Would you mind to explain and edit your question to make it clearer?

Comment: Hi @Hsien, thank you for the edit ! :) I modified wat was requested

Comment: is it that hard this question ?

Comment: The statement that p = O(1) is meaningless since p cannot possibly be more than 1.  Do you mean that p = Theta(1), i.e., that it is a fixed constant that does not depend on n?